# SFML createMaskFromColor() not working correctly

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm creating a game where I have 3 separate objects to display. A floor, a player sprite and multiple crates. Below is the code for all three.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{

    std::ifstream fileHndl;

    fileHndl.open("Assets/mapdata.txt");

    fileHndl >> mapCols;
    fileHndl >> mapRows;

    playerX = mapCols / 2;
    playerY = mapRows / 2;

    mapData = new int *[mapRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < mapRows; i++) {
        mapData[i] = new int[mapCols];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mapRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapCols; j++) {
            fileHndl >> mapData[i][j];
        }
    }

    window.create(sf::VideoMode(1280, 1024), "COMP2501 Demo");
    window.setFramerateLimit(5);

    playerImage.loadFromFile("Assets/actor.png");
    playerImage.createMaskFromColor(sf::Color::White);
    playerTexture.loadFromImage(playerImage);
    playerTexture.setSmooth(true);
    playerSprite.setTexture(this->playerTexture);

    floorTexture.loadFromFile("Assets/floor.png");
    floorTexture.setSmooth(true);

    crateImage.loadFromFile("Assets/crate.png");
    crateImage.createMaskFromColor(sf::Color::White);
    crateTexture.loadFromImage(crateImage);
    crateTexture.setSmooth(true);

    mapSprites = new sf::Sprite *[mapRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < mapRows; i++) {
        mapSprites[i] = new sf::Sprite[mapCols];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mapRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapCols; j++)
        {
            mapSprites[i][j].setPosition(j * 64, i * 64);
            if (mapData[i][j] == 1)
            {
                mapSprites[i][j].setTexture(this->floorTexture);
            }
            else
            {
                mapSprites[i][j].setTexture(this->crateTexture);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm attempting to remove the white background of all 3 images as they're all .pngs however when doing so I get the following result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG3H2.png

The crates appear to be drawing a black border around themselves. Is there a better way to go about removing the white background on PNGs as textures?

Crate
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA5Dv.png

Comment: It works fine for the player sprite though. Post the original crate sprite as well.

Comment: I don't have the crate set as a sprite right now, just as a texture. Should I make it a sprite?

Comment: Post this file: "Assets/crate.png".

Comment: Posted it to the thread

Comment: I think I may know the answer. Are you placing the crate sprites above the floor sprites or either floor, either crate (i.e. no overlay)?

Comment: As of right now I'm only using a texture for the crates and floor. I'm only using a sprite for the player. The order in which I place them are the same as above.

Comment: No, you didn't understand my question. By "sprite" I mean the single square picture, just that. The order above shows how you create **the objects** to use. It doesn't show how you **place** them on the field. What I wan to know is, when there is a crate "texture" in a cell, is there a floor "texture"  below the crate "texture"?

Comment: I believe you're correct. It doesn't appear to be drawing a floor texture underneath the crate texture. I've updated my question so you can see how the sprites are being displayed.

Comment: Ok, I'm posting this as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of additional information, this would be my logical chain towards a guess:

Since we see the `createMaskFromColor()` function work fine for the player model, it's not the error source. Since we see the same code being invoked for the other two objects, the chroma keying is working fine there as well. Hence, the following answer:

There is nothing but the black background behind the crate sprites. The chroma keying works correctly, and happily demonstrates us the black background behind the transparent corners.

How to fix:

Make sure the floor sprite is present behind the crate sprites as well. Maybe create an additional sprite, "crate over a floor", to not overlay them every time such a combination is encountered (no idea if this really affects performance, just a guess.)